# Call functions in function with different input arguments

Tags: python, function, qgis

I'm pretty new to python, but I didn't find 
I got a river network that I want to use a couple of algorithms on.

First step is to load the data and process it in a way I can use it.
I want a function which loads and preprocesses the data and then calls another function to process it.

Depending on the algorithm I want to call I need different input arguments.
I need to give the arguments for the algorithm into the loading algorithm.

Is there a way for the function to work in way where the function knows which argument is for a algorithm?

The way the code knows that "calc_network(data, algorithm3, inputB)" works the way I intend it.

The way I see I would need to give the input "calc_network(data,algorithm3,0,inputB,0)".

So I need to set blank-values for values I don't need correct?

```
def calc_network(data, algorithm, inputA, inputB, inputC):

     def processData(data)

         return processedData

     def algorithm1(processedData, inputA, inputB)

         return results

     def algorithm2(processedData, inputA, inputC)

         return results

     def algorithm3(processedData, inputB)

         return results

     return results, processedData
```

Is the way I think about the problem right or do I have some sort of basic misunderstanding?

Thanks in advance
Leo

Comment: Why are you defining all those functions *inside* `calc_network`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def algorithm1(data, input_a, input_b):
    return 'algorithm1 result'

def algorithm2(data, input_a, input_c):
    return 'algorithm2 result'

def algorithm3(data, input_b):
    return 'algorithm3 result'

def calc_network(data, algorithm):
    def process_data(data):
        return 'processed {}'.format(data)
    processed_data = process_data(data)
    return algorithm(processed_data), processed_data

print(calc_network('data1', partial(algorithm1, input_a=1, input_b=2)))
print(calc_network('data2', partial(algorithm2, input_a=1, input_c=3)))
print(calc_network('data3', partial(algorithm3, input_b=2)))
```

This will produce:

```
('algorithm1 result', 'processed data1')
('algorithm2 result', 'processed data2')
('algorithm3 result', 'processed data3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not nest functions like that.  You would have multiple functions, and call the child functions from the parent function.

```
def functionA(foo):
    do stuff
def functionB(foo):
    do stuff
def functionC(foo):
    do stuff using functionA or functionB
```

If you want to keep your functions in a structure similar to what you are talking about, you probably want to consider classes.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, your, data, arguments):
        Determine which function to send data to
        self.data = call function(s) and get the data.
    def algorithm1(self, processedData, inputA, inputB)
        return results
    def algorithm2(self, processedData, inputA, inputC)
        return results
    def algorithm3(self, processedData, inputB)
        return results
```

This way, when you want the data, you can do it by instantiating the class.

```
foo = Foo(your, data, arguments)
```

Then your results will be accessible with:

```
foo.data
```